# MDI Application : Home/Dashboard in Delphi berlin 10.1 application

Tags: delphi, dashboard, mdi

I am working on an MDI application in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. There is a main Form and child Forms. When I open a child form, it is displayed in the client area of the main Form, which is how an MDI application works.

My task is to show, within the main Form, a home/dashboard Form, which has some shortcut menus, grids, and some important links which should always be open on the main Form. This Form should never close. How can this Form be shown on the main Form/parent Form?

Or, is there some other, better approach, to show a dashboard in an MDI application?

Edited.
-Hi
In MDI application  i needs to show grids and other controls on main form/parent form.(on client area)
but if i did this and try to open child windows then they are not displayed/opned on parent form, as client area is occupied by grid and other controls on main form.

Comment: I suggest you add a toolbar, alt. a panel with `align = alTop` to the MDI main form and place those "dashboard" components on that toolbar/panel. Since it is aligned to the top, the MDI child forms will be shown below that toolbar/panel. If you already have the "dashboard" form ready, you could try setting its parent to the MDI main form and again align it `alTop`. I have never tried such a setup (with a form), and don't know whether there are potential problems.

Comment: Thanks for reply.but my dashboard is also child form
it opened on client area of parent form it is also fine if any other forms displayed over it when I click home button dashbord form will see again but it shold not change size and width of dashboard from

Comment: @Ankush If you don't want a child form closed, then simply don't close it. What is the real problem? Look at the Form's OnCloseQuery event, and Contraints property.

Comment: Sorry, but it is now unclear to me what you are asking. You are also expressing contradicting messages as you originally said (copied from your original post): *But here is my taks to show home/dashboad form which has some shortcut menus,grids and some Imp links which always open on main form.* Note, you say **always open on main form**, not on a child form! Please edit your question and add simplest possible code that replicates the error, and try to improve the problem description.

Comment: I did update description

Answer (score 0):

I am **not** claiming this solution is a "*good*" solution, and you should definitely use something else than MDI when you want to do what you are trying to do.

But here's a go on it:
You could create the mainform as a "normal" form, and create each child form as a normal form. Then in the child forms oncreate you set the window parent to the mainform. *This is no MDI*, and **it's not good practice either**!

But it will allow you to hover your child windows over the controls placed on the mainform. You will to add some code to the form onclick to bring the form to the front when you click on the child form.

[image: You will get something like this]

I added a listview (just a plain listview) to show the forms can hover over the listview.
But like others already mentioned, MDI is deprecated since Win2K and for good reason. So i would definitely go for a tabbed layout or use some good docking library like LMD docking pack, which can create a MDI "like" interface.

Comment: In tabbed layout can we see multiform forms at one time?

Comment: You could to the same with a tabbed interface, but if you realy like MDI i would suggest taking a look at LMD Docking Pack. You can simulate a MDI with thsese components, and allow your user to dock them to a tabbed interface